# Upload video to Facebook with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, video

I am trying the following code to upload a non-resumable video from my disk to my Facebook profile using Javascript.

```
    FB.setAccessToken(accessToken);

    let vid = "file:///D:/videos/vid.mp4";
    //also tried with "D://videos/vid.mp4"

    FB.api(
        "/me/videos ",
        "POST",
        {
            "source": vid,
            "filename": "vid.mp4"

        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        }
    );
```

Every time I execute this, I get the following error within a couple of seconds.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 390,
        "error_subcode": 1363030,
        "is_transient": true,
        "error_user_title": "Video Upload Time Out",
        "error_user_msg": "Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.",
        "fbtrace_id": "GwPTrdyQe7z"
    }
}
```

I have looked into the documentation to find if there is some parameter for timeouts but all in vain.

Please guide me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For file uploading fron facebook api you should use file-system

```
let vid = "file:///D:/videos/vid.mp4";
let videoData = require('fs').createReadStream(vid);
FB.api(
    "/me/videos ",
    "POST",
    {
        "source": videoData,
    },
    function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    }
);
```

hope this will help.

Comment: require('fs') does not we use require in node js how we will upload it using JavaScript in the browser.  ?

Comment: and what if we want to show progress bar during the video upload...?

Comment: How do you do this on remote url's?